# How should I reuse functions on a number of different Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have now written a number of different functions in Google Apps Script that I am using on a growing number of Google Spreadsheets.

Every time I make a small edit to one of these functions I then have to go into each spreadsheet and make the same correction.

Is there a way to "import" the functions to each spreadsheet so that I only have to edit the one "master" function and it is then updated on every spreadsheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has just release a new feature called Libraries, it is an elegant way to do what you're asking for. [Here is the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries), read it attentively because it's a multi-step process.

Answer (score 0):

See this page for how to create and share functions in your sheets using Google Apps Scripts. The scripts are written in javascript and there are some limitations on how they can be used.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_writing_scripts#CustomFunctions

Comment: I don't see how this helps me... it doesn't seem to relate to my question as to how I re-use my functions in other spreadsheets and then not having to edit every spreadsheet when I make a change to the function.